# How to use the variable generated by Include Controller's calling .jmx in current script?

Tags: jmeter

In my every API request, I use authtoken which is generated before the API service runs. I have created the script for authtoken and extracting that token by using JSON XTRACTOR with a variable name "authToken" and saved a file Token.jmx. Now, I want to use this Token.jmx file in my current script by using include controller so that before run my actual API, token should generate and pass this token stored in authToken for further API requests.

Below is my scenario:
ThreadGroup
-->OncleOnlyController
    -->IncludeController(calling external Token.jmx(has a variable authToken))
SimpleController
-->APIService1(https://127.0.01:4444?authtoken=${authToken)}) 
-->APIService2(https://127.0.01:4444?authtoken=${authToken)})

Is there a way to do this? How can I use the variable from the file calling by include controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) and ensure that it does not have the following statement:

```
WARN o.a.j.c.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
```

If it does - make sure your `Token.jmx` file has [Test Fragment](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) defined, otherwise nothing from there will be executed. All the JMeter Variables generated in the referenced by the Include Controller(s) file(s) will be normally available and accessible as `${authToken}`

Comment: Solved by your inputs. Thanks a ton! There was a warning and then I added Test Fragment.